# How to get list of changes between two commits, from Git server

Tags: git, git-pull

Imagine there is one git user with read access. at the first time he clones a repo on his machine. then he finds out that there is a new bunch of change and do pull the repo (*pull <strike>request</strike> #1*).

Some hours later he told to do pull again (*pull <strike>request</strike> #2*). so how can he get list of changes between the [latest commits] from these two pulls <strike>requests</strike>?

Comment: I edited/struckout out pull "request" - Q&A resembles git "pull" & "commit", not pull request (see difference of the terms at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585407/git-pull-vs-pull-request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concrete code changes you can use `git diff`.

```
git diff <sha1 of pull request #1> <sha1 of pull request #2>
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: How can we just get list of file names?

Comment: @silvercover `git diff --name-only`

Comment: @silvercover take look at the documentation I've linked to in my answer. You can find any relevant option there.

Comment: I've found it.  git diff --name-only

Answer (score 1):

`git log` accepts a range parameter:

```
git log <1st sha>..<2nd sha>
```

Comment: The double dot syntax isn't very intuitive when used the first time. Take a look at the [*Revision selection* chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) of the progit book.