# backup of stashes using Git - required?

Tags: git

I am using Git with Source tree. How can I make sure all my current stashes  from my feature branch are not deleted, after uninstalling Source tree? I don't know if they are kept on the server or my local machine, where do I check that?

My guess is the stashes will be kept because Source tree is just a GUI ... right?

For applying my local stashed changes on another PC I could create a patch (Actions-Create patch) from Source Tree, or do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are stored in your physical location of the mapped repository.Patch is the best one for your purpose.

If your changes are in one file then you can create a Snippet in bitbucket which will be stored bitbucket server.

One more option is git pull request. That also stores changes in server.

Comment: Mahesh, what do you mean about git pull storing my changes on the server? I have, on the contrary, been using pull to fetch the newly committed changes (by others). Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Git pull request is different from pull.see below link,          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585407/git-pull-vs-pull-request