# Is this a good use-case for forked repos?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a private GitHub repo that is a customized version of [Foundation for Emails](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails). I'll have several coworkers working with these files as sort of a 'starter' project so they can add pages and build their own emails with the customizations I've added. I don't anticipate them really contributing to the customizations or submitting pull requests back to this main repo, but they would need to be able to easily sync down updates to the main repo that I would commit. It would be nice to be able to access everyone's working repo if needed.

My initial idea was to have each person make their own Fork of the main repo to work within, setting the main repo up as an upstream and then using `git pull upstream master` in those forks when there are updates to the upstream 'main' repo.

I'm fairly new to Git and GitHub so I was wondering if this is a good use case for Forks? Or if there is a better solution to what I'm trying to accomplish. I was also looking at publishing a private npm package, but I think I would need to also create a CLI tool to create the project structure and that is a bit over my head right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/22585407/5784831?

Comment: I think helps me understand the pull command a bit more, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Pull vs. Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585407/git-pull-vs-pull-request)